# Decode base64 string to an audio file in Ionic3 and Angular5

Tags: audio, ionic3, base64, angular5

I have a **base64** string and I need decode it to an audio which I can reproduce with **Media** and **MediaObject** of ionic-cordova.

As I said, I am using **Ionic3** and **Angular5**.

Comment: Ok, what did you try and what is the problem you encountered ?

Comment: Good Morning. I am receiving an audio encoded as base64 string  and I need to reproduce it as audio using the "media" and mediaObject "ionic" tools.

Comment: Hi, Any solution for this?